# In Civilization V does a workshop help build wonders?

Tags: civilization-5

The workshop says that it adds +20% production when constructing buildings. Are wonders considered buildings?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No. Workshops do not help wonders.**

On the city screen, production is listed in the top left corner. You can see how production is calculated by mousing over the listing.

So I did a simple test. I found a city with a workshop, and looked at production while working on a building. It clearly listed "Modifier for buildings: 20%". I changed the city to working on a wonder, and that modifier disappeared, and production dropped appropriately.

Comment: Oh dang!! I felt much better before I read this ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Since version **[1.0.1.217](http://forums.2kgames.com/showthread.php?89117-Patch-Notes)** (1st March 2011) the workshop now *does* help with the construction of wonders.

As per the patch notes:

> Workshop provides 2 production (bonus reduced to +15% but affects ALL production); cost increased

Answer (score 1):

I wondered this, since The Pyramids, Pentagon etc. are buildings in real life. However The Pyramids isn't a Building in Civ 5 - it's a Wonder. This difference is indicated when you choose what you are going to build next: the options are grouped into Units, Buildings, Wonders, and Other.
(But workshops are still really useful imo.)